# How do I send the same message to different outputs in logstash?

Tags: logging, logstash

I have a quite common use-case regarding log handling. I want to

1. read log files
2. Send them to logstash (I am using elastic/filebeat)
3. Parse, format, save to elasticsearch, kibana, etc.
4. AND I want to have a raw backup of these log files.

It is the fourth point I cannot solve at the moment. I can save the extracted/parsed message, but I would like to have the whole raw line. Is there any way to do this with logstash?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the original log `message` unaltered you can send that to a file in raw format as below with `logstash` `output`:

```
output{
   file {
         path => "/var/logstash/logstash-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.log"
         message_format => "%{host}:%{type}:%{message}"
    }
}
```

Omit or add fields you want in the log file by editing `message_format`. If you want each type of log in sepearte file edit `path`

Comment: To be explicit, you would have *two* output{} stanzas - one for elasticsearch and one for file.  Note that in logstash1, the pipeline would block if one output was blocked.  They were working on that for logstash2, but I don't know if (or how well) it was addressed.

Comment: That is actually my whole question, is the message altered when I add filters? For example, when parsing APACHECOMBINED, is the message variable in that case, still the raw line?

Comment: If you check `APACHECOMBINED` `grok` you can see, it is not modifying the actual `message` so it can be send to a file as raw output. As long the actual `message` field is not modified using the Logstash filters, you can get raw log.